# Choosing the right OAuth2 grant type for PHP web app

Tags: php, rest, oauth-2.0

I'm building a very typical web app product. It will likely have corresponding mobile apps in the future. I'm building it from the ground up with a REST API, which is secured using OAuth2. I've got OAuth2 working, and I'm able to connect successfully using various grant types.

What I'm a little confused about is what grant types to use for the actual web app. Here's what I had in mind:

### Public API access

Before a user logs into the web app, some API access is required for things like user registration and password resets. I was thinking of using the `client_credientials` grant type. A simple client id and secret validation in return for an access token.

However, it seems totally unnecessary to request an access to token for every single public request or even for each session. It seems to make more sense to just generate ONE access token that my web app will always use.

Yet, this seems to go against how OAuth is designed to work. For example, access tokens expire. What is the right way of doing this?

### Private user API access

Next, for a user to login to the web app I was planning on using the `password` grant type (resource owner password credentials). This approach allows me to save the `user_id` with the access token—so I know which user is logged in. Further, by using scopes I can restrict access within the API.

I plan to save the access token within the PHP session. As long as the PHP session is active they will remain logged into the web app.

Is this an appropriate design for user login?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Public API Access:

One method is to skip tokens all together and just use Basic HTTP Authentication for API access.  You could accept Client Credentials for this, and limit what clients can do using client-specific scopes.  Github offers [HTTP Basic authentication](http://developer.github.com/guides/getting-started/#authentication) using user credentials for all their API calls.

For Private user API Access:

This is an interesting question because it begins to breech the line between `Authentication` and `Authorization`.  OAuth is used for `Authorization`, so logging in users becomes dicy.  Session management, for example, is something not covered by the OAuth2.0 spec.

However, this is a common use of OAuth2.0 anyway.  You can use the `password` grant type, or any other grant type for that matter, to obtain an access token.  A major downside is they have to trust your application with their password (Not a big deal for your own app, but for 3rd parties not so much).  Also, being logged in one place does not necessarily mean being logged in somewhere else (rather than SSO, you have "linked accounts", so the sessions are managed separately).  One way around this is to ALWAYS send users to the oauth authorize endpoint, and if their session is active on the OAuth2.0 Provider side, reroute them back to the client app with an access token or authorization code.  This way, if the session is active with the OAuth2.0 provider, the client can immediately log them in.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this question Brent, much appreciated! Interesting idea using Basic HTTP Authentication instead of Client Credentials. I had considered that, it just felt silly to do. My thought was "surely OAuth2 can handle this".

Comment: Also, good point on authentication vs authorization. Honestly, I have a hard time understanding where each start and stop. I've mostly looked at other APIs to see how they're doing it. I've noticed that the rules/recommendations are one thing, and how it's actually being done is a totally different thing.

Comment: I have found the same thing.  I've heard it said by security experts that you should never use a security library in ways it was not intended, so I'm reticent to recommend using OAuth2.0 for an SSO-flow.  However, if you use OAuth2.0 to "link accounts" rather than to "log users in", you should be okay.