# Salla OAuth with PHP

Tags: oauth, callback, token, store

Can someone give us an example of how to use Salla OAuth with php And how can receive the request in callback file.

https://github.com/SallaApp/oauth2-merchant

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Choosing the right OAuth2 grant type for PHP web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18603761/choosing-the-right-oauth2-grant-type-for-php-web-app)